# How to write this functional Jacobian?

Tags: path-integral, integration

I'm trying to find the correct Jacobian for an action that is invariant under the transform $X(u)\rightarrow Y(X(u))$. It involves the functional jacobian:

$$\Omega[X] = \det\left(  \partial_n X^\mu(u)  \right)^{-1} $$

in order to make the functional integration invariant under such a transformation.

$$\int\Omega[X]DX^4 = \int\Omega[Y]DY^4$$

How can I write this? Apparently you can write it in terms of fermion fields?